# BCG Matrix in R

Tags: r, graphics

I need to do a growth-share matrix (BCG Matrix) in R. I don't know if it's possible to do in R this graphic. I would obtain a graphic as this[enter link description here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aFolio_Plot_BCG_Matrix_Example.png)

Thanks You!

Comment: The linked image is missing a scale to show how to understand that size is a function of sales volume. Points being, you can improve this plot, and it is definitely possible in R.

Comment: @Marcinthebox Can you help me with the code? Now, I am using this code (An example of e4e5f4: 
x <- 1:5
y <- 5:1
r <- seq(2, 10, 2)

symbols(x, y, circles=r, fg="white", bg="red")

Comment: @calejero How can anyone *help* with the code when there is nothing there? Sorry, but you really need to post something first in order to get *help* with it. Please show us [**what you have tried**](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) and we will do our best to help you

Comment: @calejero And how did you apply the example from @e4e5f4 to your data? Have you already written some code we can help you with? Do you have much experience of using R? There are many tutorials on the [**info page**](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info) under the `r` tag if you need some help in getting started.

Comment: @calejero - I now provide you with an example, but you will need to look into the specific plotting functions yourself in order to adjust the plot to your specific problem. Try and experiment a bit more on your own in the future - the help pages (e.g. `?plot`) can give you a got start on how to control plotting commands in R.

Comment: Hello. I haven't described this question correctly. I should have asked if you knew the existence of a package in R to do Growth-share matrix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example using some of the base plotting functions in R:

#### Example:

```
set.seed(1)
n = 10
x <- runif(n, min=0, max=2)
y <- runif(n, min=8, max=24)
z <- runif(n, min=0, max=100)

#z to cex function
a <- 1
b <- 0.02
z.cex <- a + b*z

example.cex <- seq(1,3,0.5)
example.z <- (example.cex - a)/b
example.z 


plot(x, y, pch=21, bg="orange", col="red", cex=z.cex, lwd=2, bty="n", xaxt="n", yaxt="n", xlab="", ylab="")
grid()
axis(1, at=seq(0,2,0.5), pos=16, col="green4", lwd=3)
axis(2, at=seq(8,24,4), pos=1, col="green4", lwd=3)
legend("topright", legend=c(example.z), pch=21, pt.bg="orange", col="red", pt.cex=example.cex, title="sales vol.", bg="white")
```

[image]